# reading custom tags from web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created custom tags in web.config file.These values am storing in a hash table.After storing in the hash table am reading both key and value am able to read the key but not the value.Here is my code in web.config

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="BlockIpSection">
        <section name="ipslist" type="CustomConfigurationHandler.CustomConfiguration, CustomConfigurationHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<BlockIpSection>
    <ipslist>      
        <ipaddress1 value="100"></ipaddress1>
        <ipaddress2></ipaddress2>
    </ipslist>
</BlockIpSection>
```

Here there are 2 tags section group name and section name.I have created the tags as ipaddress1 and ipaddress2.Am storing value 100 to ipaddress1 tag.

I am reading this web.config like this

```
Hashtable config = (Hashtable)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("BlockIpSection/ipslist");
foreach (string key in config.Keys)
{ 
    Response.Write(key + "<br>");           
}
```

Tags from web.config we are storing in hashtable and reading using key.when i use config[key] to read the value its giving error.

Comment: BTW what are you getting when you are reading keys ???

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
App.BlockIpSection
```

or

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlockIpSection"]
```

Comment: what is Trimlink here?

Comment: trimlink (now BlockIpSelection) is the name in the web.config

Answer (score 0):

> first of all, you need to mention **key** and **value** for both tags in **web.config** and then
>   Use **NameValueCollection** instead of **Hashtable**.

problem with **Hashtable** is given below:

[image: on Add watch]

try this Block of code:

```
NameValueCollection nvObj = new NameValueCollection();
nvObj = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MyCustomSettings") as NameValueCollection;
Response.Write(hs["key1"] + "</br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your keys and values in web. config. like this .

```
<BlockIpSection>
    <ipslist>      
        <add key="ipaddress1 " value="100"/>
        <add key="ipaddress2 " value="100"/>      
        // IP keys and values ....
    </ipslist>
</BlockIpSection>

Hashtable config = (Hashtable)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("BlockIpSection/ipslist");
foreach (DictionaryEntry dicEntry in config)
//OR
// foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> dicEntry in config)
{
    string key = Convert.ToString(dicEntry.Key);
    string val = Convert.ToString(dicEntry.Value);
    // Your code goes here   
}
```